# add active class to selected item react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a react parent component and if a user clicks on one of the two options a different child component is rendered.

Depending upon which option has been selected I want to add an `active` class.

See my code below.

I have taken many approaches but have stripped them off for the question as I could not figure it out.

```
class Test extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            currentView: 'one'
        };

        this.showOne = this.showOne.bind(this);
        this.showTwo = this.showTwo.bind(this);
    }

    showOne() {
        this.setState({
            currentView: 'one'
        });
    }

    showTwo() {
        this.setState({
            currentView: 'two'
        });
    }

    render(){
    ......
        <p className="one" onClick={this.showOne}>One</p>
        <p className="two" onClick={this.showTwo}>Two</p>
    ......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<p className={this.state.currentView === 'one' ? 'one active' : 'one'} onClick={this.showOne}>One</p>
<p className={this.state.currentView === 'two' ? 'two active' : 'two'} onClick={this.showTwo}>Two</p>
```

Comment: thats the one. muchas gracias hombre! :-)

Comment: If you can use ES6 template literals: ```className={ `one ${ this.state.currentView === 'one'  ?  ' active' : '' } }```, avoids repeating `one` class